Pollyjs delay request using timing: Timing.fixed(200) is not working in ember test environment
Pollyjs delay request using timing: Timing.fixed(200) is not working in ember test environment, but in development mode it delays request by 200ms

test.polly.server.post("/api").configure({timing: Timing.fixed(200), logging: true});

Did you resolve this? what was the problem?
